# A Namespace Can Not Contain Members

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I am trying to set up my global.asax file to register routes and i can't seem to import namespaces i created

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SportStore.App_Code" %>


<script   runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

there is a copy of what i am trying to do but the third import line keeps giving me an error, I would just remove it but without it the compiler does recognize my RouteConfig class any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

here is code for the class

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SportStore.App_Code
{

    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute(null, "list/{category}/{page}",                "~/Pages/Listing.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute(null, "list/{page}", "~/Pages/Listing.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute(null, "", "~/Pages/Listing.aspx");
```

I am using the pre generated VS global.asax file

Comment: Maybe the namespace is just `SportStore` and `App_Code` is a member?

Comment: Try with `<%@ Import Namespace="SportStore.App_Code" %>`. BTW, app_code is one of ASP.NET folders. Have you actually created that namespace by hand or by adding c# files to that folder (using the templates that automatically create the namespace/class definition)?

Comment: Get rid of the `;`? Pretty sure it does not belong since you are technically not in code, but just giving it a name of the namespace.

Comment: `Application_Start` needs to be a class in a c# file.

Comment: I made a class in app code called RouteConfig added the namespace then added the methods and so on.... also i removed the ";" but the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved the problem something is wrong with the naming convention. When I changed the name to another namespace I had it worked don't know why though.